# Can I create Project Template on Eclipse like on Visual Studio

Tags: java, eclipse

Visual Studio can easily create a project template from an existing project by exporting project template and it will magically appears in visual studio template directory and in IDE.

Does Eclipse have such a feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I don't know of a way to do this. But the simplest hack I can think of would be to export an existing project and keep a folder somewhere of templates you could quickly import, rename, and go on with.

Looks like there have been some aborted attempts at doing this in the past - see sourceforge.net/projects/protewiz/ - but it doesn't look like that project's been updated in over a year.

And it looks like CDT has some project template facilities (see help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/Howtodeveloptemplates.html and help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/Howtoregistertemplates.html).

Hope that helps a bit.